# Error message for required field always showing

Tags: php

I have an error for a required field, but even when it has been filled in, its showing my error message, maybe I need an else statement but not exactly sure.

```
session_start();
// this sets variables in the session
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die("Couldn't make connection.");
$err = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM users WHERE `banned` = '0'") or 
die  (mysql_error());

if(empty($_SESSION['$user_id']))  // user not logged in; redirect to somewhere else
if (!empty($_POST['doThesis']) && $_POST['doThesis'] == 'Save')
{
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM users WHERE `banned` = '0'") or 
die (mysql_error());


 list($id) = mysql_fetch_row($result);

 if(empty($abstract))
 {
 $err[] = "ERROR - Enter Abstract";
 //header("Location: thesis.php?msg=$err[0]");
 }
 /// Automatically collects the hostname or domain  like example.com)
 $host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
 $host_upper = strtoupper($host);
 $path   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');

if(empty($err)) {
        for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST["other"]); $i++)
        {
            $thesis_Name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['thesis_Name'][$i]);
            $abstract = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['abstract'][$i]);


$sql_insert = "INSERT into `thesis`
     (`user_id`,`thesis_Name`,`abstract`  )
VALUES
     ('$id','$thesis_Name','$abstract' ";

 mysql_query($sql_insert,$link) or die("Insertion Failed:" . mysql_error());
        }

 header("location: myaccount.php?id=" . $_SESSION['user_id']. "");
}
```

}
Obviously the second header is where it should go when data is in the box. If I include the first header, the error message is in the URL bar where when I don't include the header line it is on the page (where it should be) help!!

I mean when I get an error it is the error I have set up, 'enter abstract' is displayed all the time, even when something is entered.

Comment: Can you add the exact error message ???

Comment: it is in there, `Enter abstract` the one I have set up.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly update your question with the error and what exactly you want to achieve .. becasue after looking at your code .. many  things are  wrong

A . Using foreach on `mysql` link

```
// this sets variables in the session
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die("Couldn't make connection.");
```

B . Multiple If statement that contradict each other

```
if(empty($_SESSION['$user_id']))  // user not logged in; redirect to somewhere else
if (!empty($_POST['doThesis']) && $_POST['doThesis'] == 'Save')
{
```

C. `{`  not properly closed ...

D. Multiple Instance of unused query

```
$result = mysql_query ( "SELECT `id` FROM users WHERE `banned` = '0'" ) or die ( mysql_error () );
```

`ERROR - Enter Abstract` should be the list of your problem because the reason you are having that is because you have not `declared`  `$abstract` ...

**EDIT 1 What i think you need**

```
session_start ();
// this sets variables in the session
$id = $_SESSION ['user_id'];
$link = mysql_connect ( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS ) or die ( "Couldn't make connection." ); // Database
$errors = array (); // Link

/**
 * Check if user is logged in
 */
if (empty ( $_SESSION ['$user_id'] )) {
    header ( "Location: logout.php?action=expired" ); // Change to what you want
    exit ();
}

if (! empty ( $_POST ['doThesis'] ) && $_POST ['doThesis'] == 'Save') {
    $host = $_SERVER ['HTTP_HOST'];
    $host_upper = strtoupper ( $host );
    $path = rtrim ( dirname ( $_SERVER ['PHP_SELF'] ), '/\\' );

    for($i = 0; $i < count ( $_POST ["other"] ); $i ++) {
        $thesis_Name = mysql_real_escape_string ( $_POST ['thesis_Name'] [$i] );
        $abstract = mysql_real_escape_string ( $_POST ['abstract'] [$i] );

        if (empty ( $abstract )) {

            $errors[] =" Adbstract not set for $thesis_Name" ;
            continue;
        }

        $sql_insert = "INSERT into `thesis`
            (`user_id`,`thesis_Name`,`abstract`  )
            VALUES
            ('$id','$thesis_Name','$abstract' ";

        mysql_query ( $sql_insert, $link ) or die ( "Insertion Failed:" . mysql_error () );
    }


    if(count($errors) == 0)
    {
        header ( "location: myaccount.php?id=" . $_SESSION ['user_id'] . "" );
    }
    else
    {
        print_r($errors); // Change it how you want to display your error 
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: I want to achieve the following:
- when something is entered into abstract it redirects to the second header
- when nothing is entered, it displays the error 'enter asbtract

Comment: when something is entered into abstract it redirects to the second header - when nothing is entered, it displays the error 'enter asbtract

Comment: thank you for your help but even now when I leave it empty its still returning to myaccount.php. I've deleted. I've deleted the check if user is logged in as I don't want that

Comment: my data doesn't even go into the database now

Comment: yes .. it would not go to the database if `$abstract` .. form your code you are getting `$abstract` form `$abstract = mysql_real_escape_string ( $_POST ['abstract'] [$i] );` .....